# Difference between a type and an explicitly unwrapped type in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

This one is really puzzling me: What's the difference between an implicitly unwrapped optional, and the type itself?

For example,

```
var s:String!
var s2: String
```

Aren't these two exactly the same? They represent a String that can't be nil, so why on Earth do we need the ! thing?

Answer (score 9):

The implicitly unwrapped optional is an **optional**, in fact you can assign a `nil` value

```
var s: String! = nil
```

But declaring as implicitly unwrapped, you don't have to append `?` every time you use it, so, as its name states, it is implicitly unwrapped because it is supposed to contain a non nil value.

Consequence: if an implicitly unwrapped is nil, most likely when you use it in your code a runtime exception will be generated - for instance:

```
let s: String! = nil
var s1: String = s // Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION ...
```

The question could turn into: why do implicitly unwrapped optionals exist? The answer is that they are needed to [Resolving Strong Reference Cycles Between Class Instances](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_93), and a few other cases.

I would personally avoid declaring implicitly unwrapped variables in my code, unless I have a very good reason (such as to solve reference cycles, as mentioned above)